# Asking for confirmation before closing an editor in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

TL;DR: I don't know how to present the user with a confirmation dialog before closing the `CompareEditor` defined by EMF Compare.

**More details:**

I have a relatively simple use case that I'd like to accommodate: asking the user to confirm they wish to close an editor after they have pressed the close (x) button on the workbench window.

I have determined from the [Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=307349&) that attaching an `IPartListener` to the window won't help, since its `partClosed()` method will only be invoked after the window has been closed.

The recommended solution is to implement the `ISaveablePart2` interface in the part the user is closing. However, I cannot do this, since the part comes from a plugin. In particular, it is the `CompareEditor` defined by EMF Compare. So I cannot add any additional interfaces to it. Or, if I somehow can, I don't know how to (extending the class doesn't look like an option, since it is instantiated by another EMF Compare class and not directly by my code).

Another [suggestion](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/81813/) I saw is to use an `IPerspectiveListener2` instead of the `IPartListener`, since this listener will be notified before the part is actually closed. However, I still don't know how to abort closing the part from within this listener. Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse 4? You could probably use a custom `ISaveHandler` in Eclipse 4. This is simple to do in an e4 application, not sure how to do it in a 3.x compatibility mode app.

Comment: @greg-449 I am unfortunately running in 3.x compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `ISaveHandler` to handle saves. This is an Eclipse 4 only interface which you register in the `IEclipseContext` for your main `MWindow`:

```java
MWindow window = ... get main window

IEclipseContext windowContext = window.getContext();

windowContext.set(ISaveHandler.class, ... your save handler);
```

In a 3.x compatibility mode RCP you can get the `MWindow` through the `IServiceLocator` interface offered by a number of interfaces. For example in a view or editor:

```java
MWindow window = (MWindow)getSite().getService(MWindow.class);
```

`IWorkbenchWindow` also implements `IServiceLocator`.

The custom save handler deals with telling the editor part to save and prompting the user for save actions.

The default implementation is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceSaveHandler` which you can use as a example of what is required.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I'm not sure I follow it. I am not looking to create a custom save handler, but rather to give the user the option to abort closing an editor, regardless if its contents have been saved or not.

Comment: The custom save handler 'promptToSave' method deals with aborting the save.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at the PartServiceSaveHandler implementation, but it doesn't seem to help. I am not trying to abort a save operation, I am trying to abort closing the editor regardless if it is dirty or not. In other words, I am trying to give the user the option to say "I didn't mean to press that (x) button. Please don't close my editor.". And I want to give him this option regardless of the editor state (saved or not).

Comment: If the part isn't dirty I don't know of anything that will do that.